# JMeter: Group results by header authorization?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, web-api-testing

Is there a report or some way I can show the end to end journey of a single thread based on say an authorization token in JMeter?

For example say I have the following HTTP requests:

- Registration
- Add Product
- Add Payment Details
- Submit

And then the report to show the following:

- Authorization code 1: Registration successful, Add Product successful, Add Payment Details successful, Submit successful
- Authorization code 2: Registration successful, Add Product successful, Add Payment Details successful, Submit failed
- Authorization code 3: Registration failed, Add Product failed, Add Payment Details failed, Submit failed

Is this possible? I just want a simple way to see this without having to use View Results Tree and backtrack.

Comment: For the record, I know I can select the initial request, capture the authorization header and then search for it via View Results Tree and it will highlight each request that has that header in it. I'd rather have some kind of report as I described above though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extract the header value using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
2. Add the resulting [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as a prefix or postfix to your Sampler Labels

   [image]